# CallerID in Dialogue

Tags: voicexml, rivr, voxeo

In my Rivr application I was using

> firstTurn.getParameter("nexmo_caller_id");

to get caller ID as I saw that parameter passed by Nexmo, but I've changed to Voxeo and obviously that is not working anymore. Does Rivr has any standard method to get Caller ID (remote caller number) in a Dialogue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/nuecho/rivr-cookbook/wiki/Obtaining-UUID but change `session.connection.uuid` with the session variable that contains the info. In VoiceXML 2.0, it's `session.connection.remote.uri` but Voxeo also offers `session.callerid`.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that recipe but didn't guess that the Caller ID value was retrieved the same way. I'll use the VoiceXML 2.0 standard as I don't want the code to be tied to Voxeo or Nexmo.

Answer (score 1):

Try session.connection.remote.uri and review http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/xml.vxml.variables.sessappvars

Comment: Thanks Jim, I needed the way to get that session variable using Rivr library, as explained by Gawi.